# yii, ajax, javascript not calling action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii

I am trying to post data to an action with ajax in yii.  Currently I am hard coding true and false in the action to see if I am even posting data, and it's not getting there.
I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong.  Any Information would help, Thank you

JS/AJAX below:

```
    function printObject(o) {  // alerts an object
        var out = '';
        for (var p in o) {
            out += p + ': ' + o[p] + '\n';
        }
        alert(out);
    }

    $(function() {
        var dialog, form,
            //select ticket_code, I don't know if this is working properly
            ticket_code = $( "#ticket_code"), 
            allFields = $( [] ).add( ticket_code ),
                tips = $( ".validateTips" );

        function addTicket() {
            var valid = false;
            //alert ticket_code (however, it only alerts a long error message)
            //saying that the length is 1, but not sure if that is correct
            //see link at the end for error message. 
            printObject(ticket_code);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('ticket/addTicket'); ?>',
                data: {ticket_code : ticket_code},
                success: function(){
                    alert('got here');
                    valid = true;
                }
            });
            alert("after ajax");
            if ( valid ) {
                dialog.dialog( "close" );
                alert('yay');
            }
        }
```

actionAddTicket below:

```
public function actionAddTicket(){
    if(isset($_POST['ticket_code'])){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

form view below:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add a Ticket">
<p class="validateTips">Please Enter Ticket Number</p>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="ticket_code">Ticket Code #</label>
        <input type="text" name="ticket_code" id="ticket_code" placeholder="000-0000" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" title="You can find this on the bottom right hand side of your ticket">
        <img src="/images/faq-ticket-codes.png" width="150";/>
        <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image: the alerted object value for ticket_code]

Comment: What is the HTTP response? You'll have to open your browsers debugging tools (usually F12 or Ctrl + Shift + K).

Comment: TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.
 
value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );

Comment: That looks like a JavaScript error, not an HTTP response. Can you update your question with this error and provide a stack trace?

Comment: @GregBurghardt : Is that what you meant by stack tracing, or is there a way to do it in ajax?

Comment: You should try to avoid hard code url in Ajax function body, use Yii::app-> createUrl ('controller/action') to get exact url independently  from your project setup

Comment: A stack trace is an error in JavaScript that lists out the call stack from where the code threw the error. It should list file names, function names and line numbers.

Comment: Thank you @Alejandro, I hope i did that correctly.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, it says that the error is at jquery.js (line 9476, col 16).  And that line consists of "value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );".  From that, I tried to alert out the object it is taking in from ticket_code, and it alerts what seems to be a jquery library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by two things:

1. AJAX requests are Asynchronous, which means the line of JavaScript immediately following the call to `$.ajax` gets executed before the AJAX request comes back in, or most likely will. It becomes a race condition.
2. The line `ticket_code = $( "#ticket_code")` is a jQuery object. You then pass it as the `ticket_code` property in the request `data` which jQuery is trying to serialize as a string. jQuery thinks `ticket_code` is an HTMLInputElement (e.g. `<input type="text">`) when it actually is a jQuery object, so there is no way for it to be serialized as a string.

Anything you want to do after the AJAX request comes back to the browser should be done in the `success` callback. Secondly, you need to use `ticket_code.val()` when creating your data to pass along in the request:

```
function addTicket() {
    var valid = false;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('ticket/addTicket'); ?>',
        data: {ticket_code : ticket_code.val()},
        success: function(){
            // ticket_code is valid
            dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
    });
}
```